# php repeat one value twice in the while loop (if possible)

Tags: php

I have this table:

```
emailtype:
emailtypeID      emailtype
1                 primary
2                 secondary
3                 old
```

I have this code to show emails in the input form:

```
  $sql = "SELECT * from emailtype";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
         echo 'Email <input type="hidden" name="emailtype[]" id="" value="' . $row["emailtypeID"] . '"/>'  . $row["emailtype"];
        echo '<input type="text" name="email[]" id="" /><br />';            }
```

**GOAL:**

I would like to repeat twice the `emailtypeID = 2` or `emailtype = secondary`, so that I can enter two email addresses with the secondary ID.

Is it possible in the while loop?

Thanks!

**SOLUTION:**

For anybody who needs it, this is the new code as per the Marc B suggestion.

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
      echo 'Email <input type="hidden" name="emailtype[]" id="" value="' . $row["emailtypeID"] . '"/>'  . $row["emailtype"];
      echo '<input type="text" name="email[]" id="" /><br />';
    if($row["emailtype"] == 'secondario'){
        echo 'Email <input type="hidden" name="emailtype[]" id="" value="' . $row["emailtypeID"] . '"/>'  . $row["emailtype"];
         echo '<input type="text" name="email[]" id="" /><br />';
    }
```

}

Comment: `if (id == 2) { output extra stuff }`?

Comment: thanks! Marc! Sorry, but where exactly should go the if condition?

Comment: @Marc B Thanks! I edited the question with your solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
      echo 'Email <input type="hidden" name="emailtype[]" id="" value="' . $row["emailtypeID"] . '"/>'  . $row["emailtype"];
      echo '<input type="text" name="email[]" id="" /><br />';
    if($row["emailtype"] == 'secondario' || $row["emailtypeID"]==2){
        echo 'Email <input type="hidden" name="emailtype[]" id="" value="' . $row["emailtypeID"] . '"/>'  . $row["emailtype"];
         echo '<input type="text" name="email[]" id="" /><br />';
    }   

    }
```